# Woocommerce custom importer, products do not show up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, e-commerce

Im developing a CSV product importer for WordPress (Woocommerce).

My problem is that the product does not show in the shop until I open it in edit mode and click the update button (with no changes made).

I've done some digging and found out that when the update button is pressed, Woocommerce updates post meta and adds some extra post fields to the product.

Is there any way to mimic this behavior? Or are there any essential post meta fields that i have missed (besides the defaults such as post title, description, price, sku, visible etc)?

Comment: Did you get the right post status?

Comment: By post status you mean visible right? If so yes it's all right

Comment: No, I meant the the post's `post_status` which Igor mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, it's `_visibility` meta field. Values are `visible` (Catalog/search), `catalog`, `search` and `hidden`. Set it like any other post meta: `update_post_meta($post_id, '_visibility', 'visible')`
Other possible options are `post_status` => `publish` and  `_stock_status` => `instock`

Comment: Igor visibility is set to visible already, I'll  post the meta added by woocommerce when i get my hands on a computer

Comment: Other possible options are `post_status` => `publish` and  `_stock_status` => `instock`

Comment: Publish is set, i keep my reservation for the stock status option

Comment: Is your store set to exclude out of stock items from the loop? If so, then you would also need the `_stock_status` meta mentioned here.